# Обработка http уведомления QIWI кошелька

Tags: php, qiwi

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Принимаю оплату на сайте киви, после чего на сервер должны приходить http уведомления, но не могу понять почему инструкция не работает, ранее использовал яд, там все четко работало. Вот документация киви: [Уведомления об оплате счетов](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/bill-payments/?shell#notification) (там есть и пример входящего запроса).
Вот мой код:

```
<?php
  $secret_key = 'SECRETSECRETKEYKEY';

  $sha256_hash_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_SIGNATURE_SHA256']; // Получаю заголовок

  $entity_body = file_get_contents('php://input');  // Декодирую тело входящего запроса
  $array_body = json_decode($entity_body, 1);           // в обычный массив

  $amount_currency = $array_body['bill']['amount']['currency'];
  $amount_value = $array_body['bill']['amount']['value'];
  $billId = $array_body['bill']['billId'];
  $siteId = $array_body['bill']['siteId'];
  $status_value = $array_body['bill']['status']['value'];

  $invoice_parameters = $amount_currency . '|' . $amount_value . '|' . $billId . '|' . $siteId . '|' . $status_value;

  $sha256_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $invoice_parameters, $secret_key);

  if ($sha256_hash_header == $sha256_hash && !empty($sha256_hash_header)) {
    // выполняю какой-то код, если все верно
  } else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
  }
?>
```

Почему не работает, помогите разобраться чайнику

Comment: Дебаг в помощь. Проверьте, что приходит в `$array_body`, `$sha256_hash_header` и `$sha256_hash`

Answer (score 1):

`$secret_key` выдается qiwi закодированным в Base64.

```
$sha256_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $invoice_parameters, base64_decode($secret_key));
```

Answer (score 1):

В твоем коде все правильно, за исключением того, что параметры при склейке должны быть строкой. Вот так:

```
$invoice_parameters = 
    $amount_currency."|".$amount_value."|".$billId."|".$siteId."|".$status_value;
    $invoice_parameters=(string) $invoice_parameters;
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение лучше выполняйте с помощью встроенной функции `strcmp` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php

Также выражения в условии поменять местами, а то у вас сначала идет сравнение строк, а затем проверка на пустоту.

```
if (!empty($sha256_hash_header) && strcmp($sha256_hash_header, $sha256_hash) === 0) {}
```